# Реализация поиска центра Луны

Tags: математика, matlab, octave

В статье авторства Даниэля Мортари (ссылка: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283554916_Image_processing_of_illuminated_ellipsoid#pf1a) рассказывается об одном из способов определения центра Луны. Меня интересует код для тестовой реализации этого метода (тестовый метод отличается от обычного тем, что некоторые параметры сразу принимаются константами в отличие от не тестовых случаев). Алгоритм описывается в самой статье, но суть в следующем (в статье начинать со страницы 444): сначала ищется градиент изображения, потом применяются 2 метода устранения точек-выбросов (Box-Based Outlier Identiﬁcation и RANSAC), и в завершение - подгонка по оставшимся точкам контура Луны. Вот список того, что мне не понятно на данный момент:

1. Как мне искать частные производные для тензора инерции?
2. На рисунке 7 (стр.446) как найти точку, через которую проводится прямая?
3. Точки вдоль прямой (Box-Based Outlier Identiﬁcation) - это все точки или только те, которые лежат на границе рамки?
4. Как оценивать дальние от прямой пиксели?
5. Как задать матлабовским кодом присвоение пикселям букв "D" и "U"?
6. В методе RANSAC, предложенном статьей, как на каждой итерации оценивать эллипс/окружность по m параметрам (где m = 3/5 от всех точек)?

Производная изображения (на изображении есть шум, но я его сглаживаю медианным фильтром), найденная по формулам статьи (стр. 445), теряет четвертую четверть, что, как мне кажется, не нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать код для реализации на MATLAB/Octave.

Comment: Задавайте конкретные вопросы. В статье алгоритм изложен достаточно ясно. Что у вас вызывает трудности?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, для начала, я не понимаю, каким образом в методе Box-Based Outlier Identiﬁcation пикселям присваивается буква "D" или "U", потому что в тексте говорится одно, а на картинке изображается другое. Также непонятно, откуда строится прямая границы все на той же картинке, потому что для прямой одного направляющего вектора недостаточно, нужна хотя бы одна точка, а откуда в статье берется эта точка - ни слова. Так же в методе RANSAC, который там используется, не понятно оценивать эллипс/окружность по m параметрам (где m - 3/5 от общего количества точек) .

Comment: "D"  и "U" не присваиваются, это просто маркировка углов для удобства указания в тексте. Точка на прямой - это пиксел для которого считались производные. Производные считаются для всех пикселов, для анализа выбираются только те пикселы где производная велика. Ваш вопрос про RANSAC не понятен.

Comment: https://opendatascience.slack.com/archives/C2ME5EVK7

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, по RANSAC вопрос состоит в способе оценки кривой при выбранном массиве точек. В стандартном RANSAC, насколько я понимаю, используется только 3 точки. Как RANSAC осуществляется в статье с учётом увеличения числа точек я не понимаю.

Comment: RANSAC - это приём состоящий в том что решение строится не для всего корпуса данных а для его случайно выбранной части. Цель - отделить данные которые слишком отличаются от большинства (аутлаеры) и решить задачу без них. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC. Я хочу сказать что RANSAC - это не алгоритм который решает конкретную геометрическую задачу.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я правильно понимаю, что та подгонка по Таубину, которая приводится следующим пунктом - это и есть оценка эллипса/окружности, которая указана в схеме изменённого RANSAC?

Comment: Это нигде прямо не сказано. Я думаю что вы правы и Таубин вызывается внутри RANSAC. После RANSAC решение уточняется МНК.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не совсем поняла момент с уточнением с помощью МНК. В статье, вроде, написано, что МНК - это часть метода Таубина. А он, как мы выяснили, используется внутри RANSAC.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я про производные так же спрашивала, потому что по тем формулам, которые указаны в статье, у меня пропадает четвертая четверть круга.

Comment: (МНК + Таубин): вы правы. (...четвертая четверть): нужно больше подробностей.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, поправила задачу.

Comment: Четвертая четверть: это может быть нормально, если Луна только что прошла полнолуние. Какая там оригинальная картинка? Вы делали тесты на Луне перед полнолунием?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, это изображение - сгенерировано, а не оригинальное фото. Брался обычный зашумленный белый круг.

Comment: Задавайте конкретные вопросы с полным описанием. А то это игра в угадайку началась. Зарегестрируйтесь в ODS. Ссылку я выше слал. Там вам быстрее помогут. Здесь вопрос будет или заброшен или закрыт (как неконкретный).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, кстати по поводу RANSAC: в статье на странице 438 на рисунке 1 показана схема алгоритма, судя по которой подгонка по Таубину идет после RANSAC, а потом уже нелинейный МНК помощью сигмоидальной функции. Так что вопрос о методе оценки эллипса внутри RANSAC остается открытым.

Comment: Я полагаю что сперва работает RANSAC + Taubin.  Когда найдено грубое приближение, аутлаеры по грубому приближению. Затем делаетс Taubin без RANSAC. Что-то такое. Но я не уверен, возможно текст писали люди которым RANSAC и МНК так близки, что решение подразумевается очевидным.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, отсюда я брала базовый алгоритм RANSAC для эллипсов: https://github.com/seisgo/EllipseFit/blob/master/matlab/ellipseDataFilter_RANSAC.m
А отсюда брала реализацию алгоритма Таубина: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22678-circle-fit-taubin-method
Как можно изменить код RANSAC, чтобы он выполнялся по схеме из статьи?

Comment: Я ещё раз перечитал работу. Я вас запутал. Сперва RANSAC, затем Taubin. Про RANSAC сказано, что точки выбираются не (совсем) случайно. Я думаю что в первой реализации вам не должно быть важно какой у вас RANSAC.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, как понимать первую реализацию? Это первая итерация? Тогда как действовать в последующих?

Comment: Первую версию ваше программы соберите с обычным, случайным RANSAC. Когда будет успех, RANSAC можно будет поменять на более совершенный.